# Getting success/failure Response on android.SmsManager.sendTextMessage() in NativeScript/Android

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I'm sending an SMS from my NativeScript mobile application and this is the following code:

```
sendSms(numbers, body) {
        let sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(numbers, null, body, null, null);
    }
```

The SMS successfully sends using this bit of code, but I want to get a response if the SMS has successfully sent to display to the user of my application.

Something like if it was a Promise:

```
    sms.sendTextMessage(numbers, null, body, null, null).then(res => {
       if(res=='success') someCode;
    })
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `sentIntent` and `deliveryIntent` - [see this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage) (search that page for sendTextMessage - the direct link won't work here)

Comment: I see. Any idea on how would this be implemented in NativeScript's Angular typeography, or just the regular JavaScript in NativeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone, I've looked into the PendingIntent android reference and I've written a simple NativeScript x TypeScript x Angular solution to achieve this.

Here it is below in case someone else is looking for it in the future.

```
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import * as utils from "utils/utils";

@Injectable()
export class SmsService {
    context = utils.ad.getApplicationContext();
    socket;

    constructor() {

    }

    sendSms(numbers, body) {
        let id = 'messageSent';
        let pendingIntent = this.pendingIntent(id);
        let sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(numbers, null, body, pendingIntent, null);
        this.broadcastReciever(id, () => {
            console.log('This should call after sent.');
        })
    }

    broadcastReciever(id, cb) {
        app.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(id, () => {
            cb();
        });
    }

    pendingIntent(id) {
        let intent = new android.content.Intent(id);
        return android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
```

Quick edit: in the `broadcastReciever()` function in the callback you have to unregister the Receiver, because it will register new Receivers every time you send an SMS, so this is what it looks like now:

```
sendSms(numbers, body) {
        let sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(numbers, null, body, this.pendingIntentSent, null);
        this.broadcastReciever(this.id, () => {
            console.log('@@@ SUCCESFULLY SENT @@@');
            app.android.unregisterBroadcastReceiver(this.id);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As Archer suggested, use PendingIntents to be notified when the sms has been sent, and/or delivered.

[PendingIntent.getBroadcast()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) - will retrieve a PI instance.

```
var pISent = android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new android.content.Intent(android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT), 0);
sms.sendTextMessage(numbers, null, body, pISent, null);
```

Read more on Pending Intents on the Android Docs to gain better understanding of how Android works - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html